# A question from Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds (P. 63, E. 3)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

- Let $f: \mathbf{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ and $g: \mathbf{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be differentiable. Let $F: \mathbf{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be
  defined by the equation
  $$
  F(x, y)=f(x, y, g(x, y))
  $$
  Find $D F$ in terms of the partials of $f$ and $g .$

My Attempt. Consider $x=p$, $y=k$ and $r=g(x,y)$. So

$D F=\left[\begin{array}{lll}{\dfrac{\partial p} {\partial x}} \\ {\dfrac{\partial k} {\partial y}} \\ {\dfrac {\partial r}{\partial g}}\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{lll}{1} \\ {1}  \\ {\dfrac {\partial r}{\partial g}}\end{array}\right]$

Please, may you check my attempt and how can I find $\dfrac{\partial r} {\partial g}$, may you help?

Comment: I added an answer below, may you check?

Comment: checked .  . . . !

Answer (score 1):

Make $\phi(x,y)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
g(x,y)
\end{array}\right)$ and consider $F(x,y)=f\circ\phi(x,y)$.

Then by the chain's rule you have
$F'=f'\cdot\phi'$ that is
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\rm grad}F&=&\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right]\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
\end{array}\right),\\
&=&\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\
,\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
then you will be through.

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't understand your answer. How did you make $\phi(x,y)$ and why $F(x,y)$ equal to $f\circ \phi (x,y)$? May you explain?

Comment: the choice for $\phi$ is natural because $f\circ\phi(x,y,g)=f(x,y,g)$

Comment: Why did  you write comma in your last equality? $DF$ should be$1\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: May you write formula of matrix represtation  of grad f (for any f)? I don't know this

Comment: $${\rm grad}f=\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right]$$

Comment: $\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\
,\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
\right]$ is a $1\times2$ matrix

Comment: when i write a matrix, we don't use a comma but you used the comma in the matrix $DF$, i couldn't understand

Comment: And how can I show $F(x, y) =f \circ \phi(x, y) $, can you write here, please ?

Comment: You wrote $F(x,y)=f(x,y,g(x,y))$ and$$F(x,y)=f(x,y,g(x,y))=f\circ\phi(x,y)$$

Comment: if you don't write commas, how do you identify the entries of a matrix?

Comment: for example, $$
\left[\begin{array}{ll}{1} & {0} \\ {0} & {1}\end{array}\right]
$$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix. There are no commas in the matrix

Comment: and for a row matrix any one would use the format [a, b] necessarily XD

Comment: hah, okey thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

By the chain rule

$$F_x=[f(x,y,g(x,y)]_x =f_x(x,y,g(x,y))+f_z(x,y,g(x,y)) g_x(x,y),$$

$$F_y=[f(x,y,g(x,y)]_y =f_x(x,y,g(x,y))+f_z(x,y,g(x,y)) g_y(x,y).$$

Hence,

$$DF=
\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right]_{1\times 2} 
$$

Comment: if you want your try could be a good answer, you ought to explain where those formulas, $F_x$ and $F_y$, come