# A question from Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds (P. 63, E.3, part b) )

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

- Let $f: \mathbf{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ and $g: \mathbf{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be differentiable. Let $F: \mathbf{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be
  defined by the equation
  $$
  F(x, y)=f(x, y, g(x, y))
  $$

a) Find $DF$ in terms of partials of $f$ and $g$ (There is an answer for this: [the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3426329/a-question-from-munkres-analysis-on-manifolds-p-63-e-3) )

**My question is: b)** If $F(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$, find $D_1 g$ and $D_2 g$ in terms of the partials of $f$.

How can I use chain rule to show part $b)$? May you help? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear about the notation you're using, but you may be looking for something like:

$$\frac{\partial F }{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y,g(x,y)) = f_x(x,y,g(x,y)) + f_z(x,y,g(x,y))g_x(x,y)$$

which you could then use (with the fact that $F \equiv 0 \implies F_x = 0$) to say that

$$g_x(x,y) = -\frac{f_x(x,y,g(x,y))}{f_z(x,y,g(x,y))}$$

Comment: Your notation is right, thanks for answer!